# How I define my activity as "Indoor Cycling" using CYCHealthKitHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch, healthkit

The problem is I am sending a "Cycling" activity from my app to Apple Health and I want it to appear as "Indoor Cycling" but all the activities send to apple health activity are mark as "Outdoor activity", there is any property to define them as "Indoor Cycling" activities from my code?

I research but there is only one activity to define the Cycling as you see I my code below I used: 
workoutWithActivityType:HKWorkoutActivityTypeCycling

here is a view of how my activities look in Apple Activity app 
[image: data]

```
- (void)saveWorkoutFromStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate endDate:(NSDate *)endDate duration:(double)duration miles:(double)miles kilocalories:(double)calories completion:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))completion {

    HKQuantity *milesQuantity = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit mileUnit] doubleValue:miles];
    HKQuantity *caloriesQuantity = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit kilocalorieUnit] doubleValue:calories];

    HKWorkout *workout = [HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:HKWorkoutActivityTypeCycling startDate:startDate endDate:endDate duration:duration totalEnergyBurned:caloriesQuantity totalDistance:milesQuantity metadata:nil];
    [self.healthStore saveObject:workout withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        if (success) {
            completion(success, nil);
        }
        else {
            DLog(@"%@", error);
            completion(success, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the metadata indoor workout key with a value of YES to the metadata dictionary when instantiating your workout:

```
HKWorkout *workout = [HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:HKWorkoutActivityTypeCycling startDate:startDate endDate:endDate duration:duration totalEnergyBurned:caloriesQuantity totalDistance:milesQuantity metadata:@{HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout : @(YES)}];
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkmetadatakeyindoorworkout?language=objc

Comment: This appears to be still true in iOS 13; even despite setting HKWorkoutConfiguration.locationType = .indoor. The meta data key HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout is very much needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is set on the `locationType` instance property of your `HKWorkoutConfiguration`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutconfiguration/1649491-locationtype?changes=_4&language=objc

Answer (score 0):

## Use `HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout`

`HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout` worked for me, example:

```
var isIndoorWorkout = true 
var metadata: Dictionary<String,Any> {
    var _metadata:Dictionary<String,Any> = [:]
    _metadata[HKMetadataKeySyncIdentifier] = "Your unique workout Identifier goes here"
    _metadata[HKMetadataKeySyncVersion] = yourDateCompletedAt.timeIntervalSince1970 // as an example for versioning
    _metadata[HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout] = isIndoorWorkout // <-- HERE!
    return _metadata
}
```

source: [HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkmetadatakeyindoorworkout?language=objc)